# VBA function Regex

Tags: regex, vba, function

Do you have an idea of what is wrong in this code please? It should extract all caps and the pattern "1WO" if available.
For example in "User:399595:Account:ETH:balance", i should have "UAETH" and in "User:197755:Account:1WO:balance" i should have "UA1WO"

Thank you

```
Option Explicit

Function ExtractCap(Txt As String) As String

    Application.Volatile
    Dim xRegEx As Object
    Set xRegEx = CreateObject("VBSCRIPT.REGEXP")

    If xRegEx.Pattern = "[^A-Z]" Then
    xRegEx.Global = True
    xRegEx.MultiLine = False
    ExtractCap = xRegEx.Replace(Txt, "")
    Set xRegEx = Nothing

    Else: xRegEx.Pattern = "1WO"
    ExtractCap = xRegEx.Execute(Txt)

    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Why use `If xRegEx.Pattern = "[^A-Z]"`? Just set the pattern, no need using `If`.

Comment: WO is also capitalized

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a "RegEx" expert, so you may want to try an alternative:

```
Function ExtractCap(Txt As String) As String
    Application.Volatile
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To Len(Txt)
        Select Case Asc(Mid(Txt, i, 1))
            Case 65 To 90
               ExtractCap = ExtractCap & Mid(Txt, i, 1)
        End Select
    Next
End Function
```

while, should the pattern of your data strictly be as you showed, you could also consider:

```
Function ExtractCap(Txt As String) As String
    Application.Volatile
    ExtractCap = "UA" & Split(Txt, ":")(3)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Your RegEx works like this:

```
Function ExtractCap(Txt As String) As String

    Application.Volatile
    Dim xRegEx As Object
    Set xRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With xRegEx
        .Pattern = "[^A-Z]"
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        ExtractCap = .Replace(Txt, vbNullString)
    End With

    If Txt = ExtractCap Then ExtractCap = "1WO"

End Function

Public Sub TestMe()
    Debug.Print ExtractCap("User:399595:Account:ETH:balance")
End Sub
```

In your code, there were 2 errors, which stopped the execution:

- xRegEx was set to `Nothing` and then it was asked to provide a value;
- the check `If xRegEx.Pattern = "[^A-Z]"` does not actually mean a lot to `VBA`. E.g., you are setting a `Pattern` and making a condition out of it. If you want to know whether a pattern exists in a RegEx, you should compare the two strings - before and after the execution of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be easily solved.

Firstly, I assumed that `1WO` can appears at most once in your string.

Based on that assumption, logic is as follows:

Define function, which extracts all capital letters from strings.

Now, in the main function, you split your string first using `1WO` as delimeter. Now, pass every string (after splitting) to function, get all the caps from those strings and concatenate them again with `1WO` in its place.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Extract(str As String) As String
Dim s As Variant
For Each s In Split(str, "1WO")
    'append extracted caps with 1WO at the end
    Extract = Extract & ExtractCaps(s) & "1WO"
Next
'delete lest 1WO from result
Extract = Left(Extract, Len(Extract) - 3)

End Function

Function ExtractCaps(str As Variant) As String
Dim i As Long, char As String
For i = 1 To Len(str)
    char = Mid(str, i, 1)
    If Asc(char) > 64 And Asc(char) < 91 And char = UCase(char) Then
        ExtractCaps = ExtractCaps & char
    End If
Next
End Function
```

If you put this code in inserted `Module`, you can use it in a worksheet in formula: `=Extract(A1)`.